# Firebase error says app not configured

Tags: ios, firebase

My app using firebase has worked fine up until recently it started crashing with the error saying an instance of FIRApp has not been created.

All of the solutions online say to put FIRApp.configure() in appDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions or the init() of the AppDelegate, but I have it set like this and the error still happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out Firebase changed its Cocoapods recently.

I was installing 'Firebase' and 'FirebaseUI', however these seem to have been replaced by 'Firebase/Core' (see [Available Pods here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup)).

Once I removed the older pod names with 'Firebase/Core', things went back to normal.

Comment: Hi @vikzilla, do accept this as the correct answer so that your post gets tagged properly. :)